# How do I select preceding sibling Xpath

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am reading value from the Excel using apache poi and then comparing that value with UI.
To search the record into UI, i am entering firstname and lastname as do not have any unique field. For some of records getting more than one records as a search result.Then second search i am doing on DOB.

`//div[@class='grid-canvas']/div` is giving me the total no of patients having same name. Below code shows 4 patients found.

```
<div class="ui-widget-content slick-row even" style="top:0px" xpath="1">
    <div class="custom-tooltip slick-cell l0 r0 slick-cell-patient-search-checkboxsel">
        <input type="checkbox"> </div>
    <div class="custom-tooltip slick-cell l1 r1"> ANTRA </div>
    <div class="custom-tooltip slick-cell l2 r2"> DAS </div>
    <div class="custom-tooltip slick-cell l3 r3"> 12/18/1968 </div>
    <div class="custom-tooltip slick-cell l4 r4"> 756663 </div>
    <div class="custom-tooltip slick-cell l5 r5"></div>
    <div class="custom-tooltip slick-cell l6 r6"></div>
    <div class="custom-tooltip slick-cell l7 r7"></div>
    <div class="custom-tooltip slick-cell l8 r8"></div>
    <div class="custom-tooltip slick-cell l9 r9"></div>
</div>
<div class="ui-widget-content slick-row odd" style="top:50px" xpath="2">
    <div class="custom-tooltip slick-cell l0 r0 slick-cell-patient-search-checkboxsel">
        <input type="checkbox"> </div>
    <div class="custom-tooltip slick-cell l1 r1"> ANTRA </div>
    <div class="custom-tooltip slick-cell l2 r2"> DAS </div>
    <div class="custom-tooltip slick-cell l3 r3"> 10/08/1988 </div>
    <div class="custom-tooltip slick-cell l4 r4"> 755463 </div>
    <div class="custom-tooltip slick-cell l5 r5"></div>
    <div class="custom-tooltip slick-cell l6 r6"></div>
    <div class="custom-tooltip slick-cell l7 r7"></div>
    <div class="custom-tooltip slick-cell l8 r8"></div>
    <div class="custom-tooltip slick-cell l9 r9"></div>
</div>
<div class="ui-widget-content slick-row even" style="top:100px" xpath="3"></div>
<div class="ui-widget-content slick-row odd" style="top:150px" xpath="4"></div>
```

With the name ANTRA DAS found 4 records as shown above, I want to put a tick mark for the record no2 as DOB-10/08/1988 is matching with the DOB of record which i read from excel.

I tried with the following code but did not work.

```
@FindBy(xpath="//div[@class='grid-canvas']/div")
List<WebElement> patientList;  //Giving size 4.
@FindBy(xpath="//div[@class='grid-canvas']/div/div[4]")  
List<WebElement> patientsDOB; //Giving 4 DOB(div tags)

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='txtSearchTextBox']")).sendKeys(Ex_FullName); //Reading fullname from Excel
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='imgbtnSeach']")).click();
if(patientList.size() > 1)
{
    for(int d=0; d<patientList.size(); d++)
    {
        String DOB = patientsDOB.get(d).getText();
        DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();
        String Ex_DOB = formatter.formatCellValue(sheet.getRow(r).getCell(3));**//Reading from Excel**
        if(DOB.equals(Ex_DOB))
        {
            WebElement tickOption = patientList.get(d).findElement(By.xpath("//div[1]/input"));
            tickOption.click();
        }
    }
}
else {  
    WebElement tickOption = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//body/div[@id='mainPageLayoutDiv']/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/form[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/span[1]/input[1]")); 
    tickOption.click();
}
```

Comment: Your HTML is not valid. I tried fixing it but there are still issues with mismatched closing tags, etc. Please refetch the HTML and update your question. We don't need more than 2 patients but the parent element to these I think is going to be required.

Comment: I think I figured out what the issue was and fixed it so that it's consistent. Please verify that it matches your site HTML structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a single locator but it's going to be a large one. I'll walk you through how it's constructed so hopefully it makes some sense.

This is the full XPath

```
//div[contains(@class,'slick-row')][./div[contains(@class,'r1')][text()=' ANTRA ']][./div[contains(@class,'r2')][text()=' DAS ']][./div[contains(@class,'r3')][text()=' 10/08/1988 ']]/div/input
```

At a high level, we're finding a parent DIV that contains multiple elements with specific requirements... the right two names and DOB. Once we find that DIV, find the child DIV and child INPUT. Here are the details of each step:

I'll reformat it into multiple lines so that I can break it down and explain it easier.

```
1 //div[contains(@class,'slick-row')]
2 [./div[contains(@class,'r1')][text()=' ANTRA ']]
3 [./div[contains(@class,'r2')][text()=' DAS ']]
4 [./div[contains(@class,'r3')][text()=' 10/08/1988 ']]
5 /div/input
```

Part 1 is pretty standard and you probably understand it... it finds a DIV that contains the class 'slick-row'. This is a parent DIV to each block of HTML that represents a patient and their info. There is one of these for each patient. We need to add more filters to find the right one.

Part 2 is take the potential parent DIVs from Part 1 and find one that has a descendant DIV that has a class 'r1' and also contains the text ' ANTRA ' (note the spaces around the text).

Part 3 and 4 are parallels to Part 2... just add filters to the DIV from Part 1 where they contain the name and DOB.

Once we've found the right parent DIV that has met all the filters in Steps 2-4, we need to find the child DIV that has a child INPUT. That's the final INPUT that needs to be clicked.

Now to the code. You no longer need (at least for this task) `patientList` and `patientsDOB` so they can be removed.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='txtSearchTextBox']")).sendKeys(Ex_FullName); // Reading fullname from Excel
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='imgbtnSeach']")).click();
String firstName = " ANTRA "; // read from Excel?
String lastName = " DAS "; // read from Excel?
String DOB = patientsDOB.get(d).getText();
DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();
String Ex_DOB = formatter.formatCellValue(sheet.getRow(r).getCell(3)); // read from Excel
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'slick-row')][./div[contains(@class,'r1')][text()=' " + firstName + " ']][./div[contains(@class,'r2')][text()=' " + lastName + " ']][./div[contains(@class,'r3')][text()=' " + Ex_DOB + " ']]/div/input")).click();
```

I may have the first name and last name backwards so you may need to switch the variable names.